# Firefox does not load any files (css, js, images)

Tags: css, firefox

i have a weired problem. The Firefox is not loading the css files while IE and Chrome does. 
Yes, i've cleared the cache a few times. The encoding is correct (utf8) and the file is valid (w3c). Even an older version of firefox does not solve the problem.

I should at least see the call for the css file in the networktab of firebug. There's only one call for the page i want to visit.

Even the imagefile i've added to the page is'nt loaded...

What is wrong?

Comment: Is it being loaded using a relative path or absolute path?

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: show us the `<link` where you're referencing your CSS file

Comment: I suggest you to copy the project css and html in a new folder and with new names for the html and css file and then check the same in firefox, even if that doesn't work, create a new project and copy the HTML and CSS line by line and keep constantly checking the file in FF.

Comment: Is your html file utf8 also?

Comment: here is the link tag: <link href="/css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: both html and css is utf8

Comment: when you say "not loading" do you mean it's getting file-not-found errors, or is it loading it but then not processing it correctly? Use the dev tools/firebug to check this.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but try writing your href like `href="css/styles.css"` the extra forward slash can cause problems on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is the *only* browser around which is rather 'picky' about how it wants to see assets served. Particularly for CSS files, [Mozilla has written an entire page full of info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files) detailing that Firefox will **NOT** process any CSS files that are not served with a `Content-type:text/css` HTTP header.

You should inspect the HTTP headers sent by the server in the Network tab of Firebug, and if my assumption is correct (it will probably be set to `text/plain` or perhaps even `application/octet-stream`) fix it by setting the correct definitions for the `.css` file extension in your webserver.

The [linked MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files#What_can_I_do_to_change_this.3F) contains solutions for Apache and Sun Web Server. For IIS this should always work correctly out of the box.

Comment: There is no call for neighter the css file nor the js files in the networktab of firebug, the call for the html only

Comment: Did you select the 'All' filter option underneath? It's rather impossible that it doesn't even load images.

Comment: there are no images yet ;-)

Comment: Well, link your site, because if this is *not* the problem we're just guessing in the dark.

Comment: This is just a local site on my computer. I've just started with this project.

Comment: Well, can't help you then until it's online. I can't fix mysteries I can't see if the obvious culprits are not the problem.

Comment: I added an image to the site. Even this does not appear on the site. wtf...

Comment: Are you actually running a webserver on localhost or developing with `file://` urls? You should definitely always work with a real webserver. Are there any errors in the console log?

Comment: I'm using apache. The only error that appears is: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined
http://admanager.dev/admin/marketer
Line 100" but this is because the js-files are not loaded

Comment: If you want more help, upload it to a public host and update the OP with the link. We're just grasping at straws now.